# Adaptive labels iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

Please help me. How to make adaptive labels for iPhone 5 and iPhone 6?
Labels on the left side should change its width.
Label on the right side should be right-aligned.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Without additional information, you should wrap the left labels in a view (or constrain them to have equal widths), constrain the view to the left margin, the right label to the right margin, and add a "greater than or equal than 0" horizontal space constraint between the view and the right label.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Self Sizing Cells. Place the following lines of code in the `viewDidLoad:` method of your `View Controller`:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 36.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

The `estimatedRowHeight` is your custom value.

Answer (score 0):

Using Autolayout first fix Left label from left side by assigning Leading space to SuperView.Same way fix Right label from Trailing.

As the right label has fix width it will be fix from right and as per the content size of Left label will vary. and if content increases the width and 'no of lines' property is 1 then it will truncate.

if you want label Left's height increase and decrese according to content then you can go for `estimatedRowHeight` property of `UITableView.`